# Open image in Fancybox 2 in fullscreen not sized

Tags: fancybox-2

I need an answer for a single image and Fancybox 2:

Key F toggles between Image Fullscreen and sized modes. Works great!

I would like that Fancybox opens the image **in fullscreen mode automatically** (and not in sized mode)
and that pressing the Key F toggles to sized mode.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution myself...:

in **jquery.fancybox.js**: change **fitToView   : false,**

image will open in original size and not resized...

Comment: you don't have to mess we the original fancybox js file. You can set that option in your custom fancybox initialization script